# FileNotFoundException when writing to raw file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write in file "numbers.txt". It's located in raw folder. 
I'm using this function to write in file:

```
public void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.numbers);
        String Path = url.toString();
        File f = new File(Path);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

When I run the function the Log says :

> File write failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.resource:/com.sakt.emergencymessage/2131099648: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

But the file exists and I can read from it.
And yes, I have written the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to resource files. They are read-only.

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway that I include a file to my project and write to it? @Simas

Comment: @SAKT no. You need to copy it to internal/external storage first. Preferably your application's data folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the external storage on the device. You can't and shouldn't be writing to the resources. Instead, copy the resource to the external storage, and then modify it there.